# How to enumerate all k-combinations of a set by sum?

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Suppose I have a finite set of numeric values of size n.

**Question:** Is there an efficient algorithm for enumerating the k-combinations of that set so that combination I precedes combination J iff the sum of the elements in I is less than or equal to the sum of the elements in J?

---

Clearly it's possible to simply enumerate the combinations and sort them according to their sums.  If the set is large, however, brute enumeration of all combinations, let alone sorting, will be infeasible.  If I'm only interested in obtaining the first m << choose(n,k) combinations ranked by sum, is it possible to obtain them before the heat death of the universe?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no polynomial algorithm for enumerating the set this way (unless [P=NP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem)).

If there was such an algorithm (let it be A), then we could solve the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) polynomially:

1. run A
2. Do a binary search to find the subset that sums closest to the desired number.

Note that step 1 runs polynomially (assumption) and step 2 runs in `O(log(2^n)) = O(n)`.

**Conclusion**: Since the Subset Sum problem is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), solving this problem efficiently will prove P=NP - thus there is no known polynomial solution to the problem.

---

**Edit:** Even though the problem is NP-Hard, getting the "smallest" `m` subsets can be done on `O(n+2^m)` by selecting the smallest `m` elements, generating all the subsets from these `m` elements - and choosing the minimal `m` of those. So for fairly small values of `m` - it might be feasible to calculate it.

Comment: Oh yes, thanks, it's very clear when put that way.  Would you like to be cited in the acknowledgements section of a report?

Comment: @wvoq: It will be nice, but not mandatory :). It is a very nice question!

Comment: Actually, since the OP is only interested in the first `m` answers, as ordered by their summation values, your proof is invalid. (or perhaps just inapplicable?)

Comment: @RBarryYoung: With the more specific quesiton, it is still NP hard. solve subset sum by: do a binary search to find the minimal `m` such that `sum(setNumbered(m)) > number)` and repeat. Same principle for the modified question.

Comment: @wvoq as "amit on stackoverflow", or would you prefer a real name and affiliation?

Comment: @wvoq: "amit on stackoverflow" is just fine. Will it be published somewhere? or just a project?

Comment: @amit: no it is not.  You are assuming that he has to solve for all values, including those greater than (m).  Consider: if `m < MIN(set-N)` then the OP's problem can be solved in constant time (it's always the empty set).  if `m = MIN(set-N)` then it can be solved in O(n) time (just search the set for single values equal to m).  If I have just proved that `P=NP` then have them send my Fields medal in the mail, but I'm pretty sure that all I've done is to show that the compleixty of the solution is dependent on `m` as well as `n`.

Comment: @amit, it will be at least a poster presentation, and hopefully a publication eventually.  The question about enumeration of combinations ranked by sum is a minor detail in the original scope of the project, but it was still quite helpful to have it answered.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I assume `m` is a *parameter* to the problem, and not some fixed value (otherwise the problem is not really interesting). By iteratively feeding a different `m` to the algorithm that solves the problem - one can find the minimal subset that sums more then requested number.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, so does this lead to an efficient algorithm for obtaining the first few, say, thousand combinations? :)

Comment: @amit if you're curious, m is actually a function of another parameter.  Here is the full story: for all k-combinations C, define f(C) = exp(-beta*sum(C)), and z = sum_{C in combinations} f(C).  I would like to compute the smallest set S of combinations such that sum_{C in S}(f(C)/Z) >= (1-epsilon), for 0 < epsilon << 1.  Ranking the combinations by f is equivalent to ranking them by sum so I asked about that, but ultimately I want to identify a small subset of combinations that in some sense well approximates the full Boltzmann distribution over combinations.

Comment: Oops, I've been confusing counts and sums above.  Nonetheless, the point still holds.  Clearly if m=0 then it can be solved in O(0). If m=1 then it can be solved in O(n).  In fact, you may be able to show that it's never greater than O(n^m).  And while that's pretty huge, it still polynomial in `n` (unless `m` is determined by `n`).

Comment: A more optimized solution will be to take the minimal `m` elements, generate all subsets for them and get the lowest `m`. `O(n + 2^m)`. Still exponential in `m`, and the problem yet remains NP-Hard for non-fixed `m` with the above explanation.

Comment: @wvoq: See edit (after my last comment regarding optimization) if `m` is fairly small - what you are after might be done after all...